# Skype fix causing problems

Tags: 14.04, unity, screen

I have added the following fix for skype after getting a blue flickering screen:

ubuntu-skylake-i915-video-fix-master

Although this sorted the problem out, my screen keeps going blank when I try to drag and drop files.  The only way to get it back is to return to chrome os and then come back.

Anyone know of a fix for this?

Ubuntu versio 14.04, trust unity desktop on chromebook

Comment: Sounds like a graphic driver issue. Try a later kernel, at least `linux-generic-lts-xenial`, and a later graphic drivers, [like these](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers).